# Show License Agreement link in Inno Setup while installation

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup for my application. I want to show a link (License Agreement) in Inno Setup while installation (except separate License Agreement Wizard). I want combine this link with some task. When user clicks that link it will navigate to particular URL.

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm quite late here... The following code script creates the `License Agreement` link label in the bottom left part of the wizard form. That label has a blue underlined font and a hand cursor on hover so it looks and feels like a common web page link. On its click event a specified URL is opened in a default web browser. This label is then visible on all wizard pages except the license page one:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  LicenseLinkLabel: TLabel;

procedure LicenseLinkClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, 
    ErrorCode);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  LicenseLinkLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  LicenseLinkLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  LicenseLinkLabel.Left := 8;
  LicenseLinkLabel.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
    LicenseLinkLabel.ClientHeight - 8;
  LicenseLinkLabel.Cursor := crHand;
  LicenseLinkLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
  LicenseLinkLabel.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
  LicenseLinkLabel.Caption := 'License Agreement';
  LicenseLinkLabel.OnClick := @LicenseLinkClick;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  LicenseLinkLabel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpLicense;
end;
```

And the result (click to enlarge):

[image: Click to enlarge]
[image: Click to enlarge]

Comment: If this post answered your question (even with such delay :-), you might [`consider to accept it`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541), if not, don't hesitate to leave a comment here, specifying your exact needs. Thanks!

Comment: The Inno docs didn't list a CurPageChanged, but I managed to get the show/hide working with a TWizardPage by tying in with the OnActivate and the OnNextButtonClick events.

Answer (score 3):

Create an RTF formatted license text (with Wordpad for very small file size) and type the hyperlink in the text as pure text, no extra functions needed (eg. 'http://stackoverflow.com'). InnoSetup will display this URL and make it clickable. Be aware that e-mail links do not work properly.

To try it, add the entire text to Wordpad, save as RTF and link it to InnoSetup.