# Opening a document in wizard before install

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My problem is that i would like to make an "hyperlink"(i know there is now such thing in inno) when you click label a document(rtf) with instructions will open.

> The problem: i DON'T want to copy this program along with the setup,
>   it should be inside the setup and after the installation it is no more
>   needed, thus it should be deleted or thrown out.

cant use `{tmp}` folder since it is accesed only in `[run]` phase(that is installation if i am not mistaken) and i need it earlier.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary folder is not explicitly reserved for `[Run]` section. It can be used whenever needed (it is widely used e.g. for DLL libraries). And there is no such thing as a *hyperlink label* in Inno Setup as far as I know. I've made [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255032/960757) of a *link lable* and extended it for opening files that are extracted from the setup archive into a temporary folder (a folder that is deleted when the installer terminates):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
; the dontcopy flag tells the installer that this file is not going to be copied to
; the target system
Source: "File.txt"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
var
  LinkLabel: TLabel;

procedure LinkLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  FileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\File.txt');
  // if the file was not yet extracted into the temporary folder, do it now
  if not FileExists(FileName) then
    ExtractTemporaryFile('File.txt');
  // open the file from the temporary folder; if that fails, show the error message
  if not ShellExec('', FileName, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode) then
    MsgBox(Format('File could not be opened. Code: %d', [ErrorCode]), mbError, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  LinkLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  LinkLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  LinkLabel.Left := 8;
  LinkLabel.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - LinkLabel.ClientHeight - 8;
  LinkLabel.Cursor := crHand;
  LinkLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
  LinkLabel.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
  LinkLabel.Caption := 'Click me to read something important!';
  LinkLabel.OnClick := @LinkLabelClick;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  LinkLabel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpLicense;
end;
```

Comment: Forget to ExtractTemporaryFile :D haha THANKS a lot