# How to change the color of the hyperlink in RTF text in Inno Setup

Tags: hyperlink, inno-setup, rtf

I'm using code from [How to add clickable links to custom Inno Setup WelcomeLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154573/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-custom-inno-setup-welcomelabel/37155253):

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  RichViewer: TRichEditViewer;
begin
  RichViewer := TRichEditViewer.Create(WizardForm);
  RichViewer.Left := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Left;
  RichViewer.Top := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Top;
  RichViewer.Width := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Width;
  RichViewer.Height := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Height;
  RichViewer.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Parent;
  RichViewer.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  RichViewer.TabStop := False;
  RichViewer.ReadOnly := True;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;

  RichViewer.RTFText :=
    '{\rtf1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ' +
    '{\b {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com/" }}' +
    '{\fldrslt{CLICK_HERE}}}} ' +
    'consectetur adipiscing elit.}';
end;
```

And I want to change the color of the hyperlink to blue:

[image]

How do I use a syntax for changing changing hyperlink color in RTF from the [answer by Oliver Bock to What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536287/850848) with the above code?

```
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue238;}
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "URL"}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1Text to display}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, on Windows 7, the link color is not blue by default (it is on Windows 10).

The correct RTF syntax to force a certain link color is like:

```pascal
RichViewer.RTFText :=
  '{\rtf1 ' +
  '{\colortbl ;\red238\green0\blue0;}' +
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ' +
  '{\b {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com/" }}' + 
  '{\fldrslt{\cf1 CLICK_HERE\cf0 }}}} ' +
  'consectetur adipiscing elit.}';
```

[image: Red link on Windows 7]
[image: Red link on Windows 10]