# Inno Setup insert a logo/image in between text

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a custom welcome page sample mentioned below which I am trying to create. I need to insert a logo/image in between the text of a custom welcome page.

[image: Welcome Page sample]

The sample code and RTF file is available in the below links:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: Welcome.rtf; Flags: dontcopy

[CustomMessages]
ISCustomPage1_Caption=Welcome to the Installation Wizard
ISCustomPage1_Description=This is a welcome page
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  ISCustomPage1: TWizardPage;
  RichEditViewer1: TRichEditViewer;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  RtfName: string;
  Rtf: AnsiString;
begin
  { Creates custom wizard page }
  ISCustomPage1 :=
    CreateCustomPage(
      wpWelcome, CustomMessage('ISCustomPage1_Caption'),
      CustomMessage('ISCustomPage1_Description'));

  { RichEditViewer1 }
  RichEditViewer1 := TRichEditViewer.Create(WizardForm);
  with RichEditViewer1 do
  begin
    Parent := ISCustomPage1.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(0);
    Width := ScaleX(500);
    Height := ScaleY(270);
    ReadOnly := True;
    ScrollBars := ssVertical;

    RtfName := 'Welcome.rtf';
    ExtractTemporaryFile(RtfName);
    if LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' +RtfName), Rtf) then
    begin
      UseRichEdit := True;
      RTFText  := Rtf;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

https://pastebin.com/fxQQFsSN

https://filebin.ca/50kCnmRieWC0

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On possible way is to embed the image into RTF document (though I didn't test it): For a similar question, see [How to add clickable links to custom Inno Setup WelcomeLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37154573/850848) – Otherwise you will have to stack multiple labels and image controls.

Comment: Using RTF (as @Martin mentioned) should work. Building your own multiline label with images would be quite painful.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys, I will work it out and let you know how it works.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. I created a custom welcome page and loaded the content from a RTF file for the welcome page. But only the text part is displayed on the page. The image is replaced by empty. I opened the RTF file using MS Word and inserted the picture via Insert --> Pictures. Does this have anything to do with the image file format? I tried with .jpg and .png.

Comment: It indeed does not work for me either. So you will probably have to try the stacked controls solution.

Comment: It seems that the next version of Inno Setup will support images in the RTF files: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/98d77a974caebc9d1e12a6c7c164a8d17e581325

Answer (score 0):

On possible way is to embed the image into RTF document.

For a similar question, see [How to add clickable links to custom Inno Setup WelcomeLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37154573/850848)

You will need [Inno Setup 6.0.4](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.0-whatsnew.htm#6.0.4) for this.

[image]

---

Or stack multiple labels and image controls.