# How to add clickable links to custom page in Inno Setup using RichEditViewer?

Tags: hyperlink, inno-setup, rtf

How to add clickable link to `RichEditViewer` in Inno Setup? I tried this solution [How to add clickable links to custom Inno Setup WelcomeLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154573/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-custom-inno-setup-welcomelabel)

Using this code below:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Page: TWizardPage;

procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  RichViewer1 : TRichEditViewer;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpReady, 'Custom', 'Page');

  RichViewer1 := TRichEditViewer.Create(Page);
  RichViewer1.Left := 0;
  RichViewer1.Top := 30;
  RichViewer1.width:=400;
  RichViewer1.WordWrap := True;
  RichViewer1.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  RichViewer1.TabStop := False;
  RichViewer1.ReadOnly := True;
  RichViewer1.Parent := Page.Surface;
  RichViewer1.ParentColor := true; 
  RichViewer1.RTFText :=  '{\rtf1 ' +
    '{\colortbl ;\red238\green0\blue0;}' +
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ' +
    '{\b {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com/" }}' +
    '{\fldrslt{\cf1 CLICK_HERE\cf0 }}}} ' +
    'consectetur adipiscing elit.}';
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin 
  CreateTheWizardPages;
end;
```

I got something like this on the custom page:

[image]

I would like to have ony one clickable link "CLICK_HERE"

I'm using Inno Setup 5.6.1, Windows 10 Pro 1909.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the code against various versions of Inno Setup compiler.

It looks like it does not work in Ansi version. It works in Unicode version. Unicode version is built using a newer version of Delphi, that's probably the reason.

You should [switch to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) in any case. And once you do that, you should upgrade to the latest version of Inno Setup (which has the Unicode version only).

Comment: yes, just installed 5.x version but Unicode :) and works. thank you. !